# Why is my Ruby Code not processing the input?

Tags: ruby, windows-7-x64

```
STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |a|
a=gets.to_i
if a >=0
 puts "a is positive"

end
end
```

Output

```
C:\Ruby221-x64\programs>ruby test2.rb
5
test2.rb:3:in `read': Interrupt
    from test2.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

Question: Why is my Ruby Code not going into the if?

Also Is the above code a way to handle continuous input? how will my code know after which input to stop. I had to press Ctrl-C to come out

Comment: This is on Ruby 2.2.1 64 bit version and on windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Your `gets` call is superfluous because the `STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |a|` already reads the inputs into `a`. So remove the `gets`:

```
STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |a|
  if a.to_i >= 0
    puts "#{a} is positive"
  end
end
```

Note that the I/O is buffered, and you're operating on a block basis, so you'll get:

Enter these inputs:

```
5
4
3
```

Press Ctrl-D to end the input (for Linux) or Ctrl-Z (for Windows), then you'll get results:

```
5 is positive
4 is positive
3 is positive

 => ["5", "4", "3"]
```

If you want this to be more interactive, then don't use the `STDIN... each` construct, but just do a loop with `gets.to_i`. For example:

```
loop do
  a = gets
  break if a.nil?    # Exit loop on EOF (ctrl-D)

  if a.to_i > 0
    puts "a is positive"
  end
end
```

If I put this into a file, say `foo.rb`, then I get:

```
OS_Prompt> ruby foo.rb
3
a is positive
5
a is positive
2
a is positive
-1
-3
2
a is positive
[ctrl-D]
OS_Prompt>
```

And it will quit the loop on ctrl-D since that will cause `gets` to return `nil`. Although in Windows, it might want Ctrl-Z.

Comment: Thanks Lurker, but pressing ctrl D did not work it was still asking for an input

Comment: @beegeeAssem the ctrl-D works for the first example I gave, not the second. Which case are you referring to?

Comment: For the second example you povided, it processed every input and provided answers immediately :), but could not end even after pressing ctrl-d and for both of your programs ctl-c give an interrupt message

Comment: C:\Ruby221-x64\programs>ruby ip1.rb
5
6
7
^D



7
-6
0

Comment: @beegeeAssem what version of Ruby are you using? Ctrl-D should terminate the loop in the first case because that's how `STDIN.read...` works. In the second case, ctrl-D will return from `gets` with a `nil` result. I updated my answer to look for the `nil`.

Comment: Also I wanted to know more about buffered inputs (as you mentioned that results are displayed later) and how to handle them, if you could suggest a good source

Comment: @beegeeAssem good place to start would be Google search on "Ruby flush stdout".

Comment: I am using Ruby 2.2.1 64 bit on Windows  7 64 bit

Comment: @beegeeAssem I put my latest updated answer into a file (`foo.rb`) and ran `ruby foo.rb` and it behaved as I would expect. Ctrl-D terminated the program gracefully. In Windows, it probably wants Ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 0):

```
▶ loop do
▷   b = STDIN.gets.to_i
▷   break if b.zero?
▷   puts b > 0 ? 'positive' : 'negative'
▷ end
#⇒ 5
# positive
# -4
# negative
# 0
# => nil
```

Comment: Just curious, what editor/IDE/terminal/REPL do the arrows come from?

Comment: @MarkThomas Custom `pry` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

`STDIN.read.split("\n").each do |a|`

This line is already taking input continuously then whats the need of gets.

```
while(true)
   b= gets.chomp.to_i
   puts b >=0 ? "b is positive" : "b is negative"
end
```

Here chomp is used to remove `\n` from the input